# Use RedirectMatch in <Location

Tags: apache

i need to redirect with my apache server some soap request to another server.
I use in my .conf different  because I have to manage more sceanarios.

For one scenario I need to intercept parameters from the incoming url for redirect it in a second url.

I use this:

```
<Location /WelcomePage>
    SetHandler weblogic-handler
    WebLogicCluster claawmdcca02:30600,claawmdcca03:30600,claawmdcca04:30600
    RedirectMatch ^/WelcomePage/documenti/getPdfFile/(.*)?idDocumento=(.*) /rest/api/submit-job/WelcomePage?Param1=$1&Param=$2
</Location>
```

for redirect
/WelcomePage/documenti/getPdfFile/**20210319**?idDocumento=**xoO1Bg4.pdf**
to
/rest/api/submit-job/WelcomePage?Param1=**20210319**&Param2=**xoO1Bg4.pdf**

but it doesn't work, apache tell me..."INDEX PAGE is ok for default"

Some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

A `RedirectMatch` in a `Location` doesn't make sense, I'd suggest doing something like this:

```
<Location "/WelcomePage">
    SetHandler weblogic-handler
    WebLogicCluster claawmdcca02:30600,claawmdcca03:30600,claawmdcca04:30600
</Location>
<LocationMatch "^/WelcomePage/documenti/getPdfFile/(.*)?idDocumento=(.*)">
    Redirect /rest/api/submit-job/WelcomePage?Param1=$1&Param=$2
</LocationMatch>
```

But I haven't tested this.

See the [LocationMatch](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#locationmatch) and [Redirect](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directive documentation.